# Roblox lua. Spaces in the area name

Tags: lua, roblox

Need to find out whether the player has unlocked the area or not. Everything works perfectly with areas in the name of which there are no spaces, and the script refuses to work with spaces. Who is not difficult, please help. It should work with the "Neutral Area" and "Future Area".

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local msg = Instance.new("Message", player.PlayerGui)

if (game.Players.LocalPlayer.AREAS.Neutral Area.Value == true) then
msg.Text = "true"
else
msg.Text = "false"
end
wait (2)
msg:Destroy()
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have spaces in Lua names. So this indexing operation is invalid!

```
game.Players.LocalPlayer.AREAS.Neutral Area
```

Usually you would use a name like `NeutralArea` or `Neutral_Area`.

The proper way to index a field named `Neutral Area` is

```
game.Players.LocalPlayer.AREAS["Neutral Area"]
```

`t.name` is syntactic sugar for `t["name"]` which only works if the key is actually a valid Lua name/identifier. Valid Lua names consist of underscore and alphanumeric characters. But they may not start with a number...

Please read the Lua manual. This is very basic knowledge.

Comment: And how to explain this? [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_8bjWmyea6m-lEi_M-1VUmUCNl8_irYu/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Vsevolod I dont see anything that link that changes the context of your question.

Comment: I din't say you can't use names like "Neutral Area". but if you do you must index it using `["Neutral Area"]`  you cannot use `.Neutral Area`